# Prove that the range of $f(x)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$ if $\left | f(x) - f(y) \right | \geq \left |x - y\right |$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\left | f(x) - f(y) \right | \geq \left |x  - y\right |$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the range of $f(x)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I found a solution [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h569909p3345868) which goes like:

> If $f(x)=f(y)$ then $0\geq |x-y|$, so $x=y$, thus $f$ is injective, therefore monotone (being injective). Since $|f(x) - f(0)| \geq |x|$, it means $f$ is both lower and upper unbounded, thus its range is the whole $\mathbb{R}$ (and moreover, $f$ is a bijection).

---

I understood that $f$ is upper unbounded as $|f(x)|\geq x$ for positive reals, but how do they got $f$ to be lower unbounded?

Comment: We don't know $|f(x)|\geq x$ for positive $x,$ we know $|f(x)-f(0)|\geq x.$

Answer (score 2):

We already know $f$ is monotone and injective, assume WLOG it is strictly increasing.
As $f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, its range is connected and thus is an interval.

If this interval was bounded above, using that $f$ is increasing we would get $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)= c$$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (because the limit of an increasing function is either finite or $+\infty$).

But this would imply that for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ we would have $$|f(x)-c|<1, \space x\geq x_0$$

Thus, $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 2$ for $x,y\geq x_0$, so taking $x,y\geq x_0$ such that $|x-y|>2$ we reach a contradiction with the condition satisfied by $f$.

The fact that this interval is not bounded below follows by a symmetric argument. As the only interval not bounded below nor above is $\mathbb{R}$, the result is proved.

Answer (score 0):

You can deduce that $f$ has to be monotone directly from the hypothesis (rather than deducing it from injectivity):

Let $g\colon \mathbb R^2\backslash \Delta \to \mathbb R$ be the function $g(x,y) = \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$, where $\Delta = \{(x,x): x \in \mathbb R\}$.  Then by assumption $|g(x,y)|\geq 1$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \backslash \Delta$, and $g(x,y) = g(y,x)$. Now if $U_{+} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x>y\}$ and $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in U_+$ then the path $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to U_+$ given by $\gamma(t) = ((1-t)x_1+tx_2, (1-t)y_1+ty_2)$ has $\gamma(0) =(x_1,y_1)$ and $\gamma(1)=(x_2,y_2)$. But then $g(\gamma(t))$ is a continuous function, so that $g(\gamma(0))$ and $g(\gamma(1))$ must have the same sign since $g\circ \gamma$ is continuous and $g$ does not vanish on $U_+$. It follows that $g$ has constant sign on $U_+$ and, replacing $f$ with $-f$ if necessary, we may assume that $f(x)>f(y)$ whenever $x>y$, that is, $f$ is increasing.

But now replacing $f(x)$ by $f(x)-f(0)$ if necessary, we may assume that $f(0)=0$. But then if $x>0$ then $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=|f(x)-f(0)| \geq x$, and similarly $f(-x)\leq x$. Thus $f([-R,R])\supseteq [-R,R]$ so that $[-R,R]\subseteq f(\mathbb R)$ for all $R>0$, and hence $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say $f$ is lower bounded, WLOG take $f$ to be increasing. Then we must have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$ exists, say $L$. We first assume $L<0$. Now equivalently, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta$ such that $$x<-\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
Hence, there must be some $a$ small enough so that $f(a)=L+\dfrac{1}{2}$. Then $|f(a+1)-f(a)|\ge|a+1-a|=1$ but $f(a+1)<f(a)$, this means $f(a+1)=L-\dfrac{1}{2}$. Clearly we get a contradiction.

The positive $L$ case can be done similarly.

Comment: Your assumention doesn't allow you to prove $f(x)\to -M.$ You need to assume $-M$ is the supremum of the lower bounds.